# Get Inno Setup 'Don't create a start menu folder' option value in code

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm working on a Inno Setup script which should check if a start menu entry with the given name already exists. The script below checks if the directory exists. The problem is that it also checks the existence even if the *'Don't create a start menu folder'* option is selected and I have no idea how to get this information.

```pascal
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectProgramGroup then
  begin
    if DirExists(ExpandConstant('{group}')) then // if the directory is not empty
    begin   
      // I have no idea how to get the info if the user has selected
      // the create start menu folder option or not
      if { USER DID NOT SELECT THE 'Don't create a Start menu folder' OPTION } then
      begin
        MsgBox('Directory already exists. Please choose a different one.',
               mbConfirmation, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end
        else
      begin
        Result := True;
      end; 
    end
      else
    begin
      Result := True;
    end; 
  end // wpSelectProgramGroup
    else
  begin
    Result := True;
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query `NoIconsCheck` checkbox directly:

```pascal
if not WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.Checked then
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for the fast response.